# Why I can't see bottom of scroller bar

Tags: html, css

I have problem with bottom of scroller bar, I don't have arrow down.

Also I added overflow-y:scroll !important;

http://jsfiddle.net/nzguLb3k/

HTML

```
<div class="first">
    <p>
        CSS image replacement is a technique of replacing a text element (usually a header tag like an <h1></h1>) with an image (often a logo). It has its origins in the time before web fonts and SVG. For years, web developers battled against browser inconsistencies to craft image replacement techniques that struck the right balance between design and accessibility.

Now that web fonts and SVG do much more of the heavy lifting for stylized text on the web, these techniques are falling out of use. But, we feel it's worth preserving them in this museum to celebrate the ingenuity that went into their creation, and to remind ourselves of a bygone era in web design.
        CSS image replacement is a technique of replacing a text element (usually a header tag like an <h1></h1>) with an image (often a logo). It has its origins in the time before web fonts and SVG. For years, web developers battled against browser inconsistencies to craft image replacement techniques that struck the right balance between design and accessibility.

Now that web fonts and SVG do much more of the heavy lifting for stylized text on the web, these techniques are falling out of use. But, we feel it's worth preserving them in this museum to celebrate the ingenuity that went into their creation, and to remind ourselves of a bygone era in web design.
    </p>

</div>
<div class="second">
   Now that web fonts and SVG do much more of the heavy lifting for stylized text on the web, these techniques are falling out of use. But, we feel it's worth preserving them in this museum to celebrate the ingenuity that went into their creation, and to remind ourselves of a bygone era in web design.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.first{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
    height:1000px;
    overflow-y:scroll !important;
}
.second{
    margin-left:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
     width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
body{
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Comment: yes, I wan't to hide overflow for body, and apply scrollbar only on my div called "first"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bottom arrow is there, you just can't see it because it's outside of the window. The window itself (styled through the body) has `overflow:hidden`.

Solution: don't apply `overflow:hidden` to the body, apply it to the second div (at least if it, as I surmise, shouldn't have scrollbars).

I also needed to apply `height` to both the html and the body, to make sure they are as high as the window.

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nzguLb3k/1/

(Note that the "calc" for the height of the body is only necessary if you keep the margins; otherwise it can just be 100%.)